# フラグメントを用いたタブバーの作成中、setFragment() でエラーが出てきました。

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments

以下のようなコードで、フラグメントを用いたタブバーを作成していたところ、`setFragment()`
の部分５つすべてで赤い波線が引かれ、Runすると不適格であるとエラーが出てしまいました。
どうすれば治るのでしょうか。どなたか教えてくださると大変助かります。

```
package com.example.********.*******;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomNavigationView mMainNav;
    private FrameLayout mMainFrame;

    private QuizFragment quizFragment;
    private CertificationFragment certificationFragment;
    private SendFragment sendFragment;
    private TakephotoFragment takephotoFragment;
    private ConsequenceFragment consequenceFragment;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mMainFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_frame);
        mMainNav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_nav);

        quizFragment = new QuizFragment();
        certificationFragment = new CertificationFragment();
        sendFragment = new SendFragment();
        takephotoFragment = new TakephotoFragment();
        consequenceFragment = new ConsequenceFragment();



        mMainNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.nav_quiz :
                        mMainNav.setItemBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
                        setFragment(quizFragment);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.nav_certification:
                        mMainNav.setItemBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
                        setFragment(certificationFragment);
                        return true;


                    case R.id.nav_send:
                        mMainNav.setItemBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
                        setFragment(sendFragment);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.nav_takephoto:
                        mMainNav.setItemBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
                        setFragment(takephotoFragment);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.nav_consequence:
                        mMainNav.setItemBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
                        setFragment(consequenceFragment);

                        default:
                            return false;

                }


            }

            private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {

                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame,fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();


            }
        });


    }
}
```

ちなみに、こちらの動画を参考に作りました。
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbcdMxAIr54&t=190s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragmentにはフレームワークが提供するクラスと、サポートライブラリが提供するクラスがあります(パッケージが違います)。

通常はサポートライブラリが提供するほうのFragmentを使うことが多いと思いますが、MainActivityではフレームワークのFragmentをimportしています。各フラグメントがどちらのクラスを使っているか確認してみてください。